# How to Distinguish Unquoted Text from Property Access in JS-Like Language?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to build a parser for a JS-like language with some unfortunate quirks. This language is provided to us by a vendor, so I do not have control over the syntax.

A simplified version of a statement takes three basic forms:
Assign (or compare!) one property to another

```
obj.prop1 = obj.prop2
```

Quoted text - could be either single quotes or double quotes

```
obj.prop1 = "quoted text"
obj.prop1 = 'quoted text'
```

Unquoted text - could be one or more words, whitespace, and punctuation

```
obj.prop1 = text
obj.prop1 = multiple words and punctuation $1,000?#-, etc
```

This case does not allow dots as far as I can tell
For case 1, I can determine assignment or comparison externally based on context.

Cases 1 and 2 are relatively easy to deal with since they are clearly distinguished. Unfortunately, case 3 is easily confused with case 1 and I haven't been able to separate them out.

To make matters worse, this pattern repeats in a sub-expression, for example, filtering an array looks like this: `obj.arrayProperty[property = value]`.

I've looked at semantic predicates and lexer modes, but haven't found a working solution via either path yet. That isn't to say there isn't one - just that I haven't found one.

Condensed versions of my lexer and parser are attached.

Is there a way for me to distinguish unquoted text from a property access?

I've tried various combinations of lexer modes and semantic predicates.

I also tried doing two passes through the parser. The first assumes quoted or unquoted text after the operator, and the second tries to treat the resulting text as a property access.

Lexer:

```
lexer grammar CondensedLexer;

AssignmentOrComparisonOperator: ('<' | '<=' | '=' | '!=' | '>' | '>=') -> pushMode(RHS);

AdditiveOperator: '+' | '-';

Identifier
    : IdentifierStartCharacter IdentifierPartCharacter*
    ;

IntegerLiteral: Sign? DecimalDigitCharacter DecimalDigitCharacter*;

Dot: '.';

fragment DecimalDigit: '0'..'9';

fragment Sign: '+' | '-' ;

fragment LetterCharacter
    // Category Letter, all subcategories; category Number, subcategory letter.
    : [\p{L}\p{Nl}]
    ;
    
fragment DecimalDigitCharacter
    // Category Number, subcategory decimal digit.
    : [\p{Nd}]
    ;

fragment IdentifierStartCharacter
    : LetterCharacter
    | UnderscoreCharacter
    ;
    
fragment IdentifierPartCharacter
    : LetterCharacter
    | DecimalDigitCharacter
    ;
    
fragment UnderscoreCharacter
    : '_'           // underscore
    | '\\u005' [fF] // Unicode escape sequence for underscore
    ;

/* 
 * these rules are important because they allow for insignificant white space to the left of the operator,
 * while retaining white space to the right of the operator. I'm sure there are better ways to do this,
 * and I'm happy to see them, but that is not my focus at the moment
 */
IWS: WS -> skip; // Insignificant white space
WS: [ \t\r\n]; // significant white space

NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n';

// RHS = right hand side - this mode allows for unquoted strings,
// single quoted strings, quoted strings, and, member accesses 
mode RHS;

fragment DoubleQuote: '"';
fragment SingleQuote: '\'';

StringLiteral
    : QuotedString
    | UnquotedString;
     
QuotedString
    : DoubleQuotedString
    | SingleQuotedString
    ;

 fragment DoubleQuotedString:
    DoubleQuote RegularStringLiteralCharacter* DoubleQuote;

 fragment SingleQuotedString:
     SingleQuote RegularStringLiteralCharacter* SingleQuote;

fragment RegularStringLiteralCharacter
    : SingleRegularStringLiteralCharacter
    | SimpleEscapeSequence
    ;

fragment SingleRegularStringLiteralCharacter
    // anything but ", \, and NewLineCharacter
    : ~["\\\u000D\u000A\u0085\u2028\u2029]
    ;

fragment SimpleEscapeSequence
    : '\\\'' | '\\"' | '\\\\' | '\\0' | '\\a' | '\\b' |
      '\\f' | '\\n' | '\\r' | '\\t' | '\\v'
    ;

 //Word: [A-Za-z_] [a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()[\]\\/ \t,|{}<>?`~]+;
 UnquotedString: ~('.')+? EOF;
```

Parser:

```
parser grammar CondensedParser;

options {
    tokenVocab=CondensedLexer;
 }

statement
    : assignmentOrComparison EOF;
    
 assignmentOrComparison
    : memberAccess IWS* AssignmentOrComparisonOperator IWS* restOfLine;
        
memberAccess
  : memberAccess Dot Identifier  
  | Identifier
  | IntegerLiteral // e.g. member.0
  ;
  
restOfLine
  : memberAccess
  | StringLiteral
;
```

Comment: So, in your example "obj.prop1 = text", how (ignoring ANTLR for the moment) do you know that it's case 3 instead of case 1?  (I would guess it's probably something like "text" is not defined (making it a semantic concern, but we shouldn't be trying to guess.)). Also, can we assume that unquoted text is terminated by a NEWLINE? (would EOF count?)

Comment: Also going to assume that the first block is some sort of cut and paste error (doesn't make sense in the context of the question, but might be email header stuff)

Comment: Yes - the first block came from my original question in the google group where I was redirected here. I don't recall seeing that when I was posting from my phone.

And yes - all statements are single lines. There would be no NEWLINE, but we would get EOF. I thought that was included in "statement: assignmentOrComparison EOF" rule? To distinguish "text" from "someField", I will need some external information passed to my visitor. If I find "text" as a field in that data, I will assume it is a reference to that. Otherwise, I will assume it is unquoted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes:

## Lexer

- Trying to use a Lexer Mode is going to result in a lot of duplicate Lexer rules as, I'm assuming, many of the LHS expressions are valid on the RHS.

```
IWS: WS -> skip; // Insignificant white space
WS:  [ \t\r\n]; // significant white space
```

`\r` and `\n` will be caught by the `IWS` Lexer rule.  We also just want to hide the WS from the parser, but not exclude it from the tokenSttream, so we'll use `channel(HIDDEN)` instead of `skip` so:

```
WS: [ \t] -> channel(HIDDEN); // Insignificant white space
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n';
```

next:

```
StringLiteral: QuotedString | UnquotedString;
```

Lexer rules don't work like parser rules, so this just treats `QuotedString` and `UnquotedString` as fragments; you'll only see `StringLiteral` tokens.  (so we'll delete it, and the Lexer rule `UnquotedString` will be moved to the Parser Rule `unquotedString`.

next:

```
UnquotedString: ~('.')+? EOF;
```

You really don't want `EOF` in a Lexer rule.  I suspect you meant `NEWLINE`, but we'll handle that differently.

We also need a token recognition of all the characters that weren't previously tokenized but could be part of an `unquotedString`

```
RandomToken: .;
```

Note: careful, we only want to match one character and it needs to be at the end of the Lexer rules, to keep it from interfering with other possible rule matches.

## Parser

I'll assume you want more than one `assignmentOrComparison` in a source file, so:

```
statement: assignmentOrComparison EOF;
```

becomes

```
statements: assignmentOrComparison* EOF;
```

We are skipping `WS` and the `NEWLINE` seems to be important as the statement terminator, so we change:

```
assignmentOrComparison
    : memberAccess IWS* AssignmentOrComparisonOperator IWS* restOfLine
    ;
```

to

```
assignmentOrComparison
    : memberAccess AssignmentOrComparisonOperator restOfLine NEWLINE
    ;
```

The main change is to the `restOfLine` rule...

```
restOfLine: memberAccess | StringLiteral;
```

becomes

```
restOfLine: memberAccess | QuotedString | unquotedString;

unquotedString
    : (
        memberAccess
        | QuotedString
        | AdditiveOperator
        | RandomToken
    )*
    ;
```

## Test

Now with the input file:

```
obj.prop1 = obj.prop2
obj.prop1 = "quoted text"
obj.prop1 = 'quoted text'
obj.prop1 = text
obj.prop1 = multiple words and punctuation $1,000?#-, etc
```

We get this parse tree: [image: parse tree]

(Sorry about the resolution, you can click on it and then zoom in to see it in detail)

this recognizes `obj.prop1 = text` as:

[image: pt1]

So you'll have to use external information to determine if it's really an `unquotedString`

And finally, `obj.prop1 = multiple words and punctuation $1,000?#-, etc` has the parse tree:

[image: pt2]

That's a lot of tokens (and ignored whitespace), but, from the `unquotedString` parent node, you can use the `getSourceInterval()` method to get the `Interval` and then use the `public String getText(Interval interval);` method on your token stream, to get the text of everything in your source code from the first token in the `unquotedString` to the last (and can just ignore the child nodes).  Careful... you want to get the text for the interval, not for the Context object itself.  The Context object will just concatenate the text of each child node, while going to the TokenStream with the interval will include all the characters between the start and end of the source for that node.

The resulting Lexer and Parser source:

```
lexer grammar CondensedLexer
    ;

AssignmentOrComparisonOperator
    : ('<' | '<=' | '=' | '!=' | '>' | '>=')
    ;

AdditiveOperator: '+' | '-';

Identifier: IdentifierStartCharacter IdentifierPartCharacter*;

IntegerLiteral
    : Sign? DecimalDigitCharacter DecimalDigitCharacter*
    ;

Dot: '.';

fragment DecimalDigit: '0' ..'9';

fragment Sign: '+' | '-';

fragment LetterCharacter
// Category Letter, all subcategories; category Number, subcategory letter.
    : [\p{L}\p{Nl}]
    ;

fragment DecimalDigitCharacter
    : [\p{Nd}]
    ; // Category Number, subcategory decimal digit.

fragment IdentifierStartCharacter
    : LetterCharacter
    | UnderscoreCharacter
    ;

fragment IdentifierPartCharacter
    : LetterCharacter
    | DecimalDigitCharacter
    ;

fragment UnderscoreCharacter
    : '_' // underscore
    | '\\u005' [fF] // Unicode escape sequence for underscore
    ;

WS:      [ \t] -> channel(HIDDEN); // Insignificant white space
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n';

fragment DoubleQuote: '"';
fragment SingleQuote: '\'';

QuotedString: DoubleQuotedString | SingleQuotedString;

fragment DoubleQuotedString
    : DoubleQuote RegularStringLiteralCharacter* DoubleQuote
    ;

fragment SingleQuotedString
    : SingleQuote RegularStringLiteralCharacter* SingleQuote
    ;

fragment RegularStringLiteralCharacter
    : SingleRegularStringLiteralCharacter
    | SimpleEscapeSequence
    ;

fragment SingleRegularStringLiteralCharacter
// anything but ", \, and NewLineCharacter
    : ~["\\\u000D\u000A\u0085\u2028\u2029]
    ;

fragment SimpleEscapeSequence
    : '\\\''
    | '\\"'
    | '\\\\'
    | '\\0'
    | '\\a'
    | '\\b'
    | '\\f'
    | '\\n'
    | '\\r'
    | '\\t'
    | '\\v'
    ;

RandomToken: .;
```

```
parser grammar CondensedParser
    ;

options {
    tokenVocab = CondensedLexer;
}

statements: assignmentOrComparison* EOF;

assignmentOrComparison
    : memberAccess AssignmentOrComparisonOperator restOfLine NEWLINE
    ;

memberAccess
    : memberAccess Dot Identifier
    | Identifier
    | IntegerLiteral // e.g. member.0
    ;

restOfLine: memberAccess | QuotedString | unquotedString;

unquotedString
    : (
        memberAccess
        | QuotedString
        | AdditiveOperator
        | RandomToken
    )*
    ;
```

Sample driver and listener:

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        new Test().run(CharStreams.fromFileName("./condensed.txt"));
    }

    public void run(CharStream charStream) {
        var lexer = new CondensedLexer(charStream);
        var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new CondensedParser(tokenStream);
        var listener = new TestListener(tokenStream);
        var tree = parser.statements();
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(listener, tree);
    }
}
```

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

public class TestListener extends CondensedParserBaseListener {
    CommonTokenStream tokenStream;

    TestListener(CommonTokenStream tstream) {
        tokenStream = tstream;
    }

    @Override
    public void enterUnquotedString(CondensedParser.UnquotedStringContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(ctx.getText());
        var interval = ctx.getSourceInterval();
        System.out.println(tokenStream.getText(interval));
    }
}
```

output:

```
multiplewordsandpunctuation$1,000?#-,etc
multiple words and punctuation $1,000?#-, etc
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike. It will take me a day or two to fully digest this, but my initial tests are very promising. Unless something strange happens, I will accept this as the answer once I've had a chance to test drive it a little and better understand how it works.

Comment: This offers some significant improvements, but I am struggling with whitespace in the unquotedText rule. Given the input "something = unquoted text" and using your suggestion above to use `TokenStream.getText`, I am getting "unquotedtext" without the space. I've uploaded a [gist of my visitor](https://gist.github.com/ccbristo/ea0eb96691d47b85f1e7699ecec39061) to github.

Comment: Sorry about that... that's what I get for doing 90% of the work and not verifying the last paragraph of stuff.  You have to send `WS` to the `HIDDEN` channel instead of skipping it, and also be careful to get the interval and use it to pull the text from the TokenStream.

Comment: Well holy moly - that did the trick. I've still got a bunch of little features to add to this language, but from what I've seen so far, dealing with unquoted text was the most difficult part. I'm amazed at how close, and yet how far, I was from a working solution. I definitely need to understand ANTLR's channels better and how the hidden channel differs from skip (there seems to be some big clues here). A huge thanks for your help!